# Recursion in Mips

Tags: recursion, mips

I'm currently trying to figure out how to code a function of finding the lowest integer in MIPS following this algorithm...

```
int Min( int[] A, int low, int high)
{   if (low== high) return A[low];
     int mid = (low+high)/2;
     int  min1 = Min( int[] A, low, mid);
     int   min2 =Min( int[] A, mid +1, high);
     if(min1>min2) return min2;
     return min1;
}
```

I'm receiving problems as I attempt to code this in MIPS. Here is my current MIPS code. The user inputs up to 6 integers which are stored in an array. The registers $a0, $a1, and $a2 are used as arguments for the function.

- $a0 = int[]A
- $a1 = int low //index
- $a2 = int high //index

Here is the recursion function...

```
min:
bne $a1, $a2, recur
mul $t4, $a1, 4
add $a0, $a0, $t4
lw $v1, 0($a0) 
jr $ra
# recursion start
recur:
addiu $sp, $sp, -12 #reserve 12 bytes on stack
sw $ra, 0($sp) #push return address
# mid = (low+high)/2 t0 = mid t1= min1 t2=min2 t3 = mid+1
add $t0, $a1, $a2 # t0 = low + high
div $t0, $t0, 2 # t0 = (low+high)/2


# mid1 = min(int[]A,low,mid)
min1:
sw $a2, 4($sp) #push high
addi $t3, $t0, 1 # mid+1
sw $t3, 8($sp) #store mid+1
move $a2, $t0 #change high to mid
jal min #compute
# check
move $t1, $v1 #set up the min1 = return value

# mid2 = min(int[]A,mid+1,high)
min2:
lw $a2, 4($sp) #reload high prior call
lw $a1, 8($sp) #change low to mid+1
jal min #compute
move $t2, $v1 #set as the min2 = return value

confirm:
# return mid2 if mid1 > mid2
bgt $t1, $t2, returnMid2
# else return mid1
move $v1, $t1
j minFinal
returnMid2:
move $v1, $t2
minFinal:
lw $ra, 0($sp)
addiu $sp, $sp, 12 #release stack
jr $ra
```

The problem is whatever combination of integers I input during the program, I never get the minimum value but rather the number "543976553". I've been looking over my code and notes and I still don't have a clue.

Comment: Why are you doing it this complicated? A simple linear search is at least as good.

Comment: Have you tried to go step-by-step for example in MARS simulator ? --> http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/download.htm

Comment: @erikkallen: I guess it's an homework exercise, something like: "Translate this C function in MIPS"...

Comment: Stupid assignment in that case. They could've made him do a binary search instead, which is not pointless.

Comment: This algorithm can be a good idea because it's parallelizable.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: A linear search is equally parallelizable.

Comment: @erikkallen A linear search would require that you manually partition the search since each iteration has write access to the same variable. On the other hand this parallel algorithm might get parallelized by some compilers, in particular those of pure functional languages.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Yes, but the amount of work required to do parallelization would be less than doing it in this roundabout way.

Answer (score 1):

For mid1, try putting the return value on the stack and then moving it to $t1 AFTER mid2 is called. Then compare $v0 with $t1 instead of comparing $t1 with $t2

Answer (score 0):

When using the div command in MIPS, doesn't one need to acquire the quotient from $LO ?

thus your logic for (high+low)/2 might look something like

```
add $t0, $a1, $a2 # t0 = low + high
addi $t5, $zero, 2 # t5=2
div $t0, $t5 # LO = t0/t5, HI = t0%t5
addi $t0, $LO, 0 # t0 = LO (t0/t5)
```

some of those lines are written just how I learned to do MIPS but you may have a different style for loading immediate values into a register.

I also can't promise this will fix everything, but at first glance, that is something I noticed.